# Spring MVC Service Implementation DAO is null

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a MVC Spring controller, in the Imp file, I have:

```
import com.is.system.dao.UserDAO;

public class CustomImpl implements CustomService {

UserDAO   userDAO = null;

public UserDAO getUserDAO() {
  return userDAO;
}

public void setUserDAO(UserDAO userDAO) {
  this.userDAO = userDAO;
}

public String ServiceType(userId) {

User user = userDAO.findById(userId);

...
```

Here is the bean that I put in applicationContext file.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.is.sm.service" />

<bean id="UserDAO" name="userDao" class="com.is.system.dao.impl.UserDAOImpl">
  <property name="sessionFactory">
     <ref bean="annotationSessionFactory" />
  </property>
</bean>

<bean id="Custom" parent="baseTransactionProxy"> 
  <property name="target"> 
    <bean id="CustomImpl" class="com.is.sm.service.impl.CustomImpl"> 
      <property name="userDAO" ref="UserDAO" /> 
    </bean> 
  </property> 
</bean>
```

Here is the error in the console:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcherServlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ish.smdb.service.impl.CustomImpl.ServiceType(CustomImpl.java:142)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
```

Here is the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/ServiceType", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String ServiceType(

            Locale locale,
            Model model) {
        String result = custom.ServiceType();

    return result;
}
```

userDAO is null. But I didn't find the reason. What am I wrong?

Comment: You have many case sensitivity problems. For the same thing I see 3 different versions: userDAO, userDao, UserDAO

Comment: Can you tell me which one?

Comment: Why not use userDAO everywhere

Comment: I used userDAO for the instantiate and UserDAO for other.

Comment: Show us your full context configuration (all of them). And the rest of your controller.

Comment: And the rest of your stack trace.